# Phonegap app, admob opens in the app,need to open in separate browser?

Tags: android, cordova, hyperlink, admob

I have a phonegap based application in which I have HTML5 code. In AdMob, I set up a mobile web app, so received a HTML to paste in. The ad shows up nicely in the application but when i click on the ad, it open inside the app itself and my application window is hidden as admob html opens within the phonegap realm. Is there a way to force admob clicks to be open on a external browser instead of having it open within the phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can. There is a new_window field which can be set to true.
http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704625

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var url;
    url = $("a").attr('href');
    $("a").attr("onclick", "window.open('"+url+"'); return false;");
  });
</script>
```